# Почему "вследствие этого" — член предложения, а "кроме этого" — не член предложения?

Tags: вводные-слова

Возьмем два одинаковых по морфологической структуре предложно-падежных выражения: **вследствие этого** и **кроме этого**.

На основании чего первое является членом предложения, а второе нет?

Предложения можно брать практически любые, какие хотите.

Comment: @Aer У нас, по-моему, имеется **сбой** в программной _оценке_ ответов сайта: ответ _user190920_ **принят**, но он (странно!) находится не на **первой** позиции. Обсмотрите, пожалуйста, странную ситуацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Она ушла, и, кроме этого, он ушел.
```

Обычно все, что с **кроме** это косвенное дополнение к прямому дополнению. **Я люблю фрукты кроме яблок**. Но у нас в таком случае прямым дополнением будет основа **он ушел**, а значит, имеем метапредложение и вводную конструкцию.

```
Она ушла и вследствие этого он ушел.
```

Обычно все, что с **вследствие** это обстоятельство. Обстоятельство имеет свойство относиться ко всему предложению (быть детерминантом). Поэтому вводными словами здесь не пахнет.

Остается вопрос, почему **кроме этого** нельзя назвать обстоятельством? Тут ответ прост. Потому что **кроме** употребляется с дополнениями. Потому что оно не будет отвечать на вопросы обстоятельств. Потому что дополнения сольются с обстоятельствами, если мы попытаемся втиснуть **кроме этого** в обстоятельства. Есть множество других вводных конструкций, которые запросто можно назвать обстоятельствами, но **кроме этого** не из этой оперы.

Answer (score 2):

«*Вообрази: я здесь одна, Никто меня не понимает…»* (А.С.Пушкин)

И, соответственно, никто не читает тоже. Поэтому оставляю **краткие тезисы,** чтобы не удалять весь ответ.

Нужно предварительно ответить на два «простых» вопроса: (1) Чем вводное слово отличается от обособленного оборота? (2) Чем ***кроме того*** отличается от ***кроме этого***? Является ли кроме этого вводным словом?

Вопрос 1. **Чем вводное слово отличается от обособленного оборота?**

Итак, все дело в грамматике, а именно в **синтаксической связи** оборота с предложением. Обособленный оборот сохраняет такую связь, а вводное слово не имеет с предложением синтаксических связей.

Розенталь относит к вводным словам сочетание ***кроме того***, а о сочетании ***кроме этого*** умалчивает. Справочник по пунктуации называет вводными оба оборота, но примеры приводит только для ***кроме того.***

Вопрос 2. **Чем "кроме того" отличается от "кроме этого"? Является ли "кроме этого" вводным словом?**

Итак, сочетания ***кроме этого*** и ***кроме того*** различаются по значению. Но почему *кроме того* считают вводным словом?

По мнению лингвистов, «вводные слова выполняют **организующую функцию,** определяя **позицию говорящего субъекта»**. Это особый синтаксический план в предложении.

Сочетание ***кроме того*** подходит для этой функции (отсылает нас вперед), а сочетание ***кроме этого*** говорит о уже сказанном. Следовательно, ***кроме этого*** — не вводное слово.

**Вывод**
Оба сочетания ***кроме этого*** и ***вследствие этого*** являются членами предложения, причем это не зависит от обособления.

Answer (score 1):

Существует предлог «кроме», и ещё существует фразеологизм «кроме того/этого», который используется как вводное слово.

> **Кроме того** (в знач. вводн. сл.) — к тому же. *Здесь восемь полковых
> оркестров и, кроме того, множество частных.* И. Гончаров, Фрегат
> «Паллада». *Мечик окончательно уверил себя в том, что Бакланов гораздо
> лучше и умней его, что Бакланов, кроме того, очень смелый и сильный
> человек.* Фадеев, Разгром. [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

В данном случае «кроме того» — это вводное слово, а вводное слово не является членом предложения.

В приведённых в словаре примерах его вообще можно убрать без особой потери смысла.
Сравните:

*Здесь восемь полковых оркестров и, **кроме того**, множество частных.*
*Здесь восемь полковых оркестров и множество частных.*

*Мечик окончательно уверил себя в том, что Бакланов гораздо лучше и умней его, что Бакланов, **кроме того**, очень смелый и сильный человек.*
*Мечик окончательно уверил себя в том, что Бакланов гораздо лучше и умней его, что Бакланов очень смелый и сильный человек.*

Тут «кроме того» использовано, как написано в вашем справочнике: *«…в функции вводного для выражения субъективного отношения к какому-либо факту, при желаний подчеркнуть его значимость»*. Т. е. «кроме того» выражает отношение говорящего.

---

Вы пишете: *«Просто меня смущает, что справочник Фрамполь трактует „Кроме этого“ совершенно однозначно»*.

Так происходит потому, что вы смотрите значение фразеологизма «кроме того», а есть ещё отдельно предлог «кроме» и указательные местоимения «тот» / «этот».

> **КРО́МЕ**, предлог с род. п.
>
> 1. За исключением кого-, чего-л., не считая кого-, чего-л. *Кроме чаек, в море никого не было.* М. Горький, Мальва. *Все улыбнулись, кроме
>    лейтенанта.* Казакевич, Весна на Одере.
> 2. Сверх кого-, чего-л., вдобавок к кому-, чему-л. *Кроме блюд и соусников, на столе стояло множество горшочков.* Гоголь, Старосветские
>    помещики. *Кроме старика, в этот день приходило к нам еще двое.* Чехов,
>    *Рассказ неизвестного человека. Вагон остановился. Теперь слышались,
>    кроме грачиных, человеческие голоса.* А. Н. Толстой, Восемнадцатый год. [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

«Кроме того/этого», как предлог с указательным местоимением, исходя из приведенных словарных значений, может значить: **за исключением того/этого, не считая того/этого, сверх того/этого, в добавок к тому/этому**.

*«И она никому не пришла бы в голову, уверяю вас, **кроме этого** немца…»*
Мамин-Сибиряк Д. Н., Приваловские миллионы, 1883

Что значит:
*«И она никому не пришла бы в голову, уверяю вас, **за исключением этого** немца…»*

И тут нельзя убрать «кроме этого» без последствий: «И она никому не пришла бы в голову, уверяю вас, немца…» — вообще непонятна мысль.

Обратите внимание, что с предлогом «кроме» указательное местоимение не является неизменяемым, как в случае фразеологизма (вводного слова) «кроме того/этого»:

*Один взгляд любви заставил бы Розу все забыть, **кроме этой** любви.*
Лажечников И. И., Последний Новик. Том 2, 1833

*Но ведь **кроме этих** драм, есть на сцене другие произведения нового времени, писанные прозой, и проза эта почти так же, как пушкинские и грибоедовские стихи, имеет свое типичное достоинство и требует такого же ясного и отчетливого исполнения, как и чтение стихов.*
Гончаров И. А., «Мильон терзаний» (критический этюд), 1871

Согласно [obrazovaka.ru](https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/krome-togo.html): когда «кроме того» является членом предложения к нему можно задать вопросы: «кроме какого?» или «кроме чего?»:

> К нему в этом случае можно поставить вопросы «кроме какого?» или
> «кроме чего?»…
>
> *Пришли все, кроме того мальчика, который вчера отказался.*
> *Мы взяли
> все, кроме того сундучка, который, как мы знали, принадлежит
> Прохорову.*

*Пришли все,* [кроме кого?] *кроме того мальчика, который вчера отказался.*
*Мы взяли все,* [кроме чего?] *кроме того сундучка, который, как мы знали, принадлежит Прохорову.*

В данном случае — это член предложения — обособленное обстоятельство.

---

«Вследствие этого» — это тоже предлог с указательным местоимением.

> **ВСЛЕ́ДСТВИЕ**, предлог с род. п. По причине, из-за чего-л. *Пишу к вам из
> деревни, куда заехал вследствие печальных обстоятельств.* Пушкин,
> Письмо М. П. Погодину, 14 апр. 1836. *На пороге ее [комнаты княжны
> Марьи] показалась — Прасковья Савишна, почти никогда, вследствие
> запрещения князя, не входившая к ней в комнату.* Л. Толстой, Война и
> мир. [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

*Силой он обладал истинно геркулесовской и **вследствие этого** пользовался большим почетом в околотке: народ наш до сих пор благоговеет перед богатырями.*
Тургенев И. С., Степной король Лир, 1870

Что значит:
*Силой он обладал истинно геркулесовской и **по причине этого** пользовался большим почетом в околотке: народ наш до сих пор благоговеет перед богатырями.*

---

**Как вывод:**

Когда «кроме того/этого» — предлог + указательное местоимение, оно является челном предложения, точно так же, как и «вследствие этого» (предлог + указательное местоимение).

Но существует еще фразеологизм «кроме того/этого», который используется, как вводное слово и, следовательно, не может быть членом предложения.

Comment: "Когда «кроме того/этого» — предлог" -- кроме того/этого - это всегда предлог с существительным, даже когда "фразеологизм". Но иногда это предложно-падежное выражение, а иногда нет. Мы ведем речь только о предложно-падежных выражениях. "Кроме этого, остался тот" -- не включает предложно-падежное выражение, и мы о таких вещах не говорим.

Comment: https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/

Comment: @user190920 По вашей ссылке «предложно-падежная форма» — это не предлог с существительным, а предлог с существительным в предложном падеже, потому и «предложно-падежная» называется, от «предложный падеж», а не от «предлог + существительное». «Того/этого» – это родительный падеж, а не предложный. Предложный будет: «о том / об этом». И вообще там идёт речь о глагольном управлении: «подумать о том / об этом». Тема: «Глагольные предложно-падежные конструкции».

Comment: @user190920 По вашей ссылке: *Предложно-падежная форма — это не только объединение имени и предлога, но и компонент конструкции — словосочетания, которое **состоит из главного слова (чаще глагольного), разрешающего выбор предложно-падежной формы**.
**Глагольное управление** — это подчинительная связь, при которой зависящее от глагола имя стоит в форме косвенного падежа и при этом создаются объектные отношения.*

Comment: Да, похоже, вы правы. Тогда скажем иначе: есть предложно-падежные сочетания, а есть устоявшиеся предложно-падежные сочетания, и речь о последних. Но все равно "кроме этого" никто не называет фразеологизмом.

Comment: @user190920 [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE):  **кро́ме того́** Устойчивое сочетание (фразеологизм). Используется в качестве вводного слова.

Answer (score 1):

"Кроме того" в функции вводного сочетания, будучи фразеологизмом, примерно равно по смыслу союзам "также" или "к тому же" плюс экспрессия - для привлечения внимания к части высказывания и связи мыслей. Произносится быстро, отделяется паузами, можно изъять. Вводное слово, поэтому не является членом предложения.
"Вследствие этого" - предлог и местоимение, изначальное значение компонентов не стерлось, не слилось, не переосмыслилось, поэтому член предложения.

Comment: Справочник по пунктуации утверждает: КРОМЕ ТОГО / ЭТОГО, вводное сочетание. Вы с ним не согласны? По каким признакам «кроме того» - это фразеологизм? Викисловарь сказал? Или есть более авторитетный источник? Зачем его нужно приравнивать к ТАКЖЕ по смыслу, что нам это дает? Изъятие слова – это еще не признак вводности, в современных учебниках написано, что вводные слова – это нечто особое, они как бы составляет метатест. У них есть особые признаки, а не только быстрое произношение и отделение паузами.

Comment: И странное у вас доказательство, основанное на внутренних ощущениях (не стерлось, не слилось, не переосмыслилось). Это не метод грамматического анализа, который требует точности.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, объяснение довольно простое, если следовать правилам Д. Э. Розенталя. Вследствие этого - предлог с местоимением, является обстоятельством. Кроме этого - по Розенталю обособленное дополнение, выраженное местоимением с предлогом. Вводными словами здесь и не пахнет.

Comment: Просто меня смущает, что справочник Фрамполь трактует "Кроме этого" совершенно однозначно: КРОМЕ ТОГО, КРОМЕ ЭТОГО, предложно-падежное 
сочетание. Употребляется в функции вводного для выражения 
субъективного отношения к какому-либо факту, при желаний 
подчеркнуть его значимость: Только такой и должна 
быть подробность - определяющей целое и, кроме того, 
обязательной (К.Паустовский); Кроме того, существуют 
сюжеты, которые ничем, кроме прозы, и не изложить 
(И.Бродский); Кроме этого, и прямо с веток падали разные 
капли, по-разному звучали (М.Пришвин).

Comment: «Вводными словами здесь и не пахнет?»  Но вот что говорит Розенталь: «Обособляются обороты с сочетаниями кроме как, кроме шуток и кроме того (в значении вводного слова)».  А это Грамота.ру, справочник по пунктуации::  КРОМЕ ТОГО / ЭТОГО, вводное сочетание.